# Negate some string pattern

Tags: regex, string, git, jenkins

In Jenkins with Git Parameter plugin (which helps me filter out tags)
I have this pattern `*-rc` this simply display all tags with `-rc` as a suffix. But how do I negate this pattern. I already have this `(?!-rc).*$` but it is not working.

**EDIT 1**

I have tags named:

3.11.2-rc

3.11.1-rc

3.11.0

3.10.0

so on and so fort...

with this pattern `*-rc` I can simply display tags with '-rc'

now, what I want to achieve is display all tags without '-rc'

**EDIT 2**

[image: jenkins git parameter config]

Comment: What do you mean *exactly* by suffix? Can you please give examples of input that should match and input that should not?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first turn on the regex option - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758534/256196) for how to do that.

Use this negative look behind based regex:

```
.*(?<!-rc)$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/mefkdcVSzCuHIV) of this regex with your sample data.

The look behind, which is anchored to end of input via `$`, requires that the preceding chars *not* be `"-rc"`.

Comment: Can you please give two examples? One that should match and one that shouldn’t?

Comment: @botjaeger I'm pretty sure you don't have the regex option turned on. See edits to my answer.

Comment: sorry, check again my question :(

Comment: This doesn't work for me too.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in [this blog post](https://namethattech.wordpress.com/2014/11/26/jenkins-git/), you could use the [Extensible Choice plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin) and:

- add '`Extensible Choice`' as a second parameter (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47880463/6309))
- write a groovy script which does the filtering for you

You can see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37810768/6309) for branches, that you can adapt for tags.

Comment: thank you for another option, but i think it is too much of an effort just to display a non '-rc' tags?